# Given a n x n matrix where each of the rows and columns are sorted in ascending order, find the kth smallest element in the matrix

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

There a O(kLogN) solution of this using heap.In worst case k=N^2.
so time complexity becomes O(N^2LogN). Is there is any better algo for this problem.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/2016/08/leetcode-kth-smallest-element-in-a-sorted-matrix-java/ , this is a popular leetcode problem

Comment: @MitchelPaulin the linked solution works only for integer matrices, and its complexity depends on the content of the matrix, not just on its size.

Comment: Yes, there's a complicated O(k)-time comparison based algorithm due to Frederickson and Johnson ("The Complexity of Selection and Ranking in X+Y and Matrices with Sorted Columns").

Comment: Well there is at least the quickselect based algorithm that doesn't take the sorted nature of the matrix into account at all, and it is O(n^2). So yeah there is a better algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat in that algoriithm the matrix only has sorted columns. If both rows and columns are sorted, there's an O(n)-time algorithm "Selection in X + Y and matrices with sorted rows and columns" due to Mirzajan and Arjomandi.